# Voltage range adapter

Tags: voltage, sensor, temperature, adapter

I have two ideas:

1. I use a temperature sensor, which is a thermocouple, where it will be connected to the input of the voltage range adapter. It will design a voltage range adapter capable of taking  low signal levels 0-30mV from the temperature sensor to translate them  in 0-1V or  0-10 DC. And the outputs of voltage range adapter  will be connected to the analog inputs of a Moeller PLC, which will displays the temperature obtained from  the temperature sensor.
2. Or I could use temperature sensor, which is a thermocouple, where it will be connected to the input of the voltage range adapter. It will design a voltage range adapter capable of taking low signal levels 0-30mV from the temperature sensor to translate them in 0-1V or 0-10 DC. And the voltage range adapter is controlled by a microcontroller to display the voltage obtained from the temperature sensor on an LCD.

What electronic schemes could you recommend?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. 1. We are NOT a 'idea' design house or your servants. 2. Please clean up your questions. 3. Horizontal elevators not needed. Just use plain English. The 'sentence' will wrap to the next line on its own. 4. Press the enter key twice to create paragraphs.

Comment: This could be reworded to be MUCH clearer... Maybe state 1) the problem you're trying to solve, then 2) your two ideas above, and finally 3) specific questions or concerns about those two ideas.

Comment: Thermocouples are not the only way to sense temp.They have very low output voltages at normal temperatures.This means that your system is much more sensitive to external interference despite good stable DC amplifier chips being cheap and easy to find .Ditch the thermocouple unless your temps are really high like 500C .

Comment: No circuit has one thermocouple and a voltmeter.   To complete a circuit, there must be two or more junctions of dissimilar metals, meaning two thermocouples, maybe more.

Answer (score 1):

You need more than a "voltage range adapter" to properly read a thermocouple. You require cold-junction compensation to get an accurate temperature reading.

Otherwise you will get a reading that is

1. inaccurate
2. dependent on the temperature of the *terminal block* of
   your "voltage range adapter", so as it warms the reading will drop!

You can get thermocouple transmitters or signal conditioners if your PLC cannot accept thermocouple inputs directly. They will work with one or more specific "flavor(s)" of thermocouple such as Chromel-Alumel (K) or Iron-Constantan (J or JIS-J).

Answer (score 0):

1. Purchase the correct analog input module for the Moeller PLC.
2. Wire your sensors to the analog input module.
3. Write the program for the PLC.
4. Write the program for the HMI/display.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a different approach.
Use AD592 instead which will give you 1uA/K. So at 20 degrees C the current will be 273.15 uA + 20 uA = 293,15 uA.

Since it is a current you will not need to bother with voltage drops on connecting wires up to approximately 1000 meters.
Using a precision resistor you can translate this current into any convenient voltage proportional to the temperature. 
The sensor is tiny which means that it reacts faster to temperature changes than sensors with greater mass.
There is more about it in its datasheet.